# Extract content with BeautifulSoup and Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrap a forum but I can't deal with the comments, because the users use emoticons, and bold font, and cite previous messages, and and and...

For example, here's one of the comments that I have a problem with:

```
<div class="content">
    <blockquote>
        <div>
            <cite>User write:</cite>
               I DO NOT WANT THIS  <img class="smilies" alt=":116:" title="116">
        </div>
    </blockquote>
    <br/>
    THIS IS THE COMMENT THAT I NEED!
</div>
```

I searching for help for the last 4 days and I couldn't find anything, so I decided to ask here.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
def make_soup(url):
    html = urlopen(url).read()
    return BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

def get_messages(url):
    soup = make_soup(url)

    msg = soup.find("div", {"class" : "content"})

    # I get in msg the hole message, exactly as I wrote previously
    print msg

    # Here I get:
    # 1. <blockquote> ... </blockquote>
    # 2. <br/>
    # 3. THIS IS THE COMMENT THAT I NEED!
    for item in msg.children:
        print item
```

I'm looking for a way to deal with messages in a general way, no matter how they are. Sometimes they put emoticons between the text and I need to remove them and get the hole message (in this situation, bsp will put each part of the message (first part, emoticon, second part) in different items).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't NavigableString helping? You can retrieve the string in a tag as described here: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `decompose` http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose

Decompose extracts tags that you don't want. In your case:

```
soup.blockquote.decompose()
```

or all unwanted tags:

```
for tag in ['blockquote', 'img', ... ]:
    soup.find(tag).decompose()
```

Your example:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = """<div class="content">
...     <blockquote>
...         <div>
...             <cite>User write:</cite>
...                I DO NOT WANT THIS  <img class="smilies" alt=":116:"    title="116">
...         </div>
...     </blockquote>
...     <br/>
...     THIS IS THE COMMENT THAT I NEED!
... </div>"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
>>> soup.find('blockquote').decompose()
>>> soup.find("div", {"class" : "content"}).text.strip()
u'THIS IS THE COMMENT THAT I NEED!'
```

### Update

Sometimes all you have is a tag starting point but you are actually interested in the content *before* or *after* that starting point. You can use `.next_sibling` and `.previous_sibling` to navigate between page elements that are on the same level of the parse tree:

```
>>> html = """<div>No<blockquote>No</blockquote>Yes.<em>Yes!</em>Yes?</div>No!"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
>>> elm = soup.blockquote.next_sibling
>>> txt = ""
>>> while elm:
...    txt += elm.string
...    elm = elm.next_sibling
... 
>>> print(txt)
u'Yes.Yes!Yes?'
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much! That was exactaly what I needed! But I'm still having problems with some comments. 
For example:


<div class="content"><blockquote><div><cite>USER:</cite>I DON'T THIS  <img class="smilies" src="./images/smilies/1arriba.gif" alt=":arriba:" title="Arriba" /></div></blockquote><br />I WANT THIS</div>


But the ouput with your code is:
USER: I DON'T WANT THIS     I WANT THIS

Comment: Hahaha you're right! I don't use this forum very often, just for search questions.

Comment: So you need 'All text in the class .content but after blockquote'?

Comment: Hmm... Supose you're in a typical forum web page. I write a comment, with emoticons, bold font, etc. A few minutes later you cite my comment (with the emoticons, bold font, etc) and you add you own emoticons, bold and italic font. Well, I need just YOUR comment, with no emoticon but the text, no matter if it's in bold, italic or regular font.

Comment: @nikolat328: Updated the answer... If you have additional questions it's okay to open a new one.

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup has a `get_text` method. [Maybe this is what you want.](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text)

From their documentation:

```
markup = '<a href="http://example.com/">\nI linked to <i>example.com</i>\n</a>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup)

soup.get_text()
u'\nI linked to example.com\n'
soup.i.get_text()
u'example.com'
```

Comment: The question is how to get `I linked to` without `example.com`.

Comment: Yes. In this case, I don't want example.com

Answer (score 0):

If the text you want is never within any additional tags, as in your example, you can use `extract()` to get rid of all the tags and their contents:

```
html = '<div class="content">\
    <blockquote>\
        <div>\
            <cite>User write:</cite>\
               I DO NOT WANT THIS  <img class="smilies" alt=":116:" title="116">\
        </div>\
    </blockquote>\
    <br/>\
    THIS IS THE COMMENT THAT I NEED!\
</div>'

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
div = soup.find('div', class_='content')
tags = div.findAll(recursive=False)
for tag in tags:
  tag.extract()
text = div.get_text(strip=True)
print(text)
```

This gives:

```
THIS IS THE COMMENT THAT I NEED!
```

To deal with emoticons, you'll have to do something more complicated. You'll probably have to define a list of emoticons to recognize yourself, and then parse the text to look for them.

Comment: Often the wanted text contains some useful tags like `em` and `strong`.

Comment: You have to find some kind of structure or pattern to the information you want to parse. There's no way Beautiful Soup can help you otherwise. You'll need to have a distinction between tags you want to keep and tags you want to throw away.